# Not just 0 but 00 remote jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching via the job alerts for remote jobs.  There is double 0 jobs available in my area for remote work:

[image]

Should be replaced with **0 remote jobs near ...**

Comment: ... or "No remote jobs near..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

His head hung in shame while he fixed the code he "fixed" earlier in the day...

Comment: Fixed looks good!

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature, weren't you just trying to make us feel like secret agents?